# Remove colorbar's borders matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

How to remove the borders on the colorbar(or make them thinner)?

I tried pretty much every combination of the following:

```
cb = plt.colorbar(im3,drawedges=False) #or True with next two lines
#cb.outline.set_linewidth(0)
#cb.dividers.set_linewidth(0)

cb.solids.set_rasterized(True)
cb.solids.set_edgecolor("face")

#Im saving as pdf
plt.savefig("thing.pdf",dpi=1000, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Some of these help when viewed with the matplotlib figure, but the saved pdf is even worse.

[image]

Comment: Does this help: http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/howto-turn-off-colorbar-frame-td27153.html

Comment: @darthbith well it completely removes it. Is there anyway to have more control over it(as well as the ticks)? Its better than nothing though.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Setting `cb.outline.set_visible()` to `False` removes the outline, both in the figure and in the saved pdf. I observed that setting the line's width to something small also was reflected in the output file.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(2,2)
im3 = plt.imshow(data)

cb = plt.colorbar(im3)

cb.outline.set_visible(False)

# this worked on matplotlib 1.3.1
#cb.outline.set_linewidth(0.05)

cb.set_ticks([])

#Im saving as pdf
plt.savefig("thing.pdf",dpi=1000, bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image: png output, but pdf worked just the same.]

Comment: to remove the ticks I used `cb.set_ticks([])`, but was unable to influence its width. Does anyone know how to do so?

Comment: `cb.ax.tick_params(length=MYLENGTH)` seems to work. See other options here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html